# Parsing multiline log message serialized by JSON with logstash

Tags: json, parsing, multiline, logstash

I have the following JSON message:

```
{
    "type":"exception",
    "content":"2014-11-25T20:11:55+00:00 ERR (3):\nexception 'Exception' with message 'some error' in \/private\/var\/www\/index.php:88\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n2014-11-25T20:11:56+00:00 ERR (3):\nexception 'Exception' with message 'some error' in \/private\/var\/www\/index.php:88\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}"
}
```

As you can see I want to parse the `content`field, which is multiline (exception log). The `\n` have been inserted while serializing to JSON. This is my logstash configuration file until now:

```
input { 
    tcp {
        port => 1337
    } 
}
filter {
    json {
        source => "message"
    }
    if [type] == "exception" {

        mutate {
            replace => ["message", "%{content}"]
            split => ["message", "\\n"]
        }
        multiline {
            pattern => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}"
            negate => true
            what => previous
        }
}
output {
    if [type] == "exception" {
        elasticsearch { host => localhost }
        stdout {
            codec => rubydebug
        }
    }
}
```

The problem here is that the multiline does not work. I thought it will act on the `message` field, therefore I replaced the message with the content field. I then also added the split in order to split the string again into lines. But that didn't work either. What am I doing wrong here?

On top questions: How can you access the output of `split`? Is it possible to split according to a regex?

Comment: The multiline filter is for joining multiple physical messages into a single message. You already have a single message. Just use a grok filter like you normally would. To have it match newline characters see the workaround in [LOGSTASH-276](https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-276).

Comment: So how is it possible to create a single log event for every exception log then? I didn't understand how they split lines by \n in the link you provided.

Comment: Wait. I now see that your single message actually contains two messages, each starting with a timestamp. Can't you do anything about that?

Comment: The problem is I send all exception messages in one json stream at all and I want to separate each exception in logstash. But anyway, I already choose to separate it before logstash. Now logstash only gets one exception at once. I tried a lot of stuff in logstash but nothing helped me getting closer to my solution. So I now parse it before logstash. Seems like logstash is not the best tool to do everything, the docs are not always helpful :-)